# Efficiently aggregate multiple columns by count

Tags: python, sql, django

Given a table

```
Table
col_1    col_2    col_3    ...
1        2        4
4        2        4
4        1        2
```

I can aggregate a single column by count with

```
Table.objects.filter(key=int).values('col_1').annotate(Count('col_1'))
```

and get the desired results for that column:

```
[{col_1: 4, col_1__count: 2}, {col_1: 1, col_1__count: 1}]
```

How can I efficiently (one database roundtrip) do this for multiple columns to achieve the following output?

```
[{col_1: 4, col_1__count: 2}, {col_1: 1, col_1__count: 1}, 
 {col_2: 2, col_2__count: 2}, {col_2: 1, col_2__count: 1}, 
 {col_3: 4, col_3__count: 2}, {col_3: 2, col_3__count: 1},
 ...                                                      ]
```